# How to place an image in table's right corner

Tags: css, html

How to place an image in table's right corner? I want set a image for an table corner.
How can I do it in html or css?

Here is example of what I want to get:

[image]

Comment: Where is the image?? Please add your image.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/v1lli.png isn't this a image??

Comment: @StevenHolzner: You need to crop the table part of the image and save it as PNG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to wrap the table in a div, set the div in relative position and the corner details image in a absolute position.

Answer (score 3):

You need a wrapper for the table as @Sonasish Roy say:

HTML:

```
<div id="container_table">
   <img src="img_right.jpg">
   <table>
     <!-- Here is your table content /-->
   </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container_table{
   position:relative;
   //Set some width because table has width:100%;
   width: 90%;
}
#container_table img{
   position:absolute;
   right:0;
   top:0;
}
#container_table table{
   //Here some css for your table, even you can use background-image, but you can have some problem with borders.
}
```

If you want to see all the above code working with an example table and image, I made  this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H3Vqc/5/